# Font color won't change

Tags: html, css, colors, frontend

This is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
    <i class="fas fa-bullseye fa-4x icon"></i>
    <h3 class="feature">Elite Designs</h3>
    <p style="color:#2F4F4F" class="points">We have all your favourite designs, the ones you can't ignore.</p>
  </div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#title .points p{
  color:#2F4F4F;
}
```

I applied this as well, but nothing worked:

```
.points{
   color:#2F4F4F;
 }
```

Comment: In that case, that content will likely enforce its own markup as inline HTML and external css is not going to work as inline CSS inside HTML. **Remove style="color:#2F4F4F"** from <p/> tag or apply important property to .points{
   color:#dedede !important;
 }

Answer (score 1):

It worked just fine when I tried it. Though, you can try using *inspect elements* to check what's going on.

```
 <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
    <i class="fas fa-bullseye fa-4x icon"></i>
    <h3 class="feature">Elite Designs</h3>
    <p style="color:#2F4F4F" class="points">We have all your favourite designs, the ones you can't ignore.</p>
  </div>
```

In this, you have used inline CSS, which can literally override any other styles you may have applied. It should work normally.

Though you can try the following in your Internal/external CSS:

```
 .points{
   color:#2F4F4F !important;
 }
```

Using ***!important*** will override any other style associating with the element. If this doesn't work as well, try clearing the Browser Cache, or using a different browser to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding `!important` to the color property

like this :

```
.points{
   color:#2F4F4F !important;
 }
```

also the `style="color:#2F4F4F"` isnt necessary here

Answer (score 0):

```
p.points{
  color:#2F4F4F !important;
}
```

Use `!important` with your code because you have used inline CSS. !important will help to override your inline CSS.

Comment: Use !important with your code because you have used inline css. !important will help to override your inline css.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this for inline styling

     <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-bullseye fa-4x icon"></i>
        <h3 class="feature">Elite Designs</h3>
        <p style="color:#2F4F4F !important;" class="points">We have all your favourite designs, the ones you can't ignore.</p>
      </div>
```

OR use below for external styling

```
p.points{
  color:#2F4F4F !important;
}

or

.points{
  color:#2F4F4F !important;
}
```

The '!important' rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property/value than normal